# Store data during application running android

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app for purchase activities. And I need to store user data (such as list of user accounts, status, etc.) during application is running. When user leaves the application (pushing "Exit" button), all data must be deleted. Also my application has a timeout: if user will not do anything during 10 minutes, it will be closed.

### What is the best way to implement data storage in such case?

Now I'm using a class with static fields to store user data, but it isn't a good solution.

1. I don't want to use Shared Preferences because I must delete all this data when user closes this application, and SP can store only primitive data.
2. And I don't want to use SQLite - I think, it's expensive, because I call account list in different classes and activities.
3. Maybe, storing data in Application subclass will be a good solution, but some people advise to avoid this way because of problems with storing data when application is in background.

Comment: `I don't want to use SQLite - I think, it's expensive` ???

Comment: Maybe you can try Realm. [It can be purged really easily](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations), it is really efficient and light and data is stored safely. However it is possible that this solution would be the same as using SQLite...

Comment: Thank you, I'll wach it. And about SQLite: is it a good way to store data only when application is running in DB? I must clean it before exit, and query data many times from different activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SQLite or Shared preference, You could consider storing data in Application Subclass.You can listen when your app goes to background or foreground by making use of lifecycle callback methods in android such as [OnPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) or [OnResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) in your activity.

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
    private static ApplicationController mInstance;

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance=this;
        //first time operations      
    }

public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

}
```

Comment: But I have more yhan 15 activities. Does it mean, that I need to override onPause and onResume methods in each activity?

Comment: You can make a parent activity and override onPause and onResume methods in it. Then make all your activities extends the parent activity.